# Python: Get a number of a list of lists which has >= 3 odd numbers "Recursively"

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I need a help to get a number of a list of lists which has >= 3 odd numbers recursively. So for example, [1, 2, 3, 4, [3, 3, 3]] returns 1 because only inner list has more than 3 odd numbers. [2, 5, 5, 5, [3, 3, 3]] returns 2 because both of outer and inner loops have more than 3 odd numbers.

The hardest part for me is to keep track of the condition of counting the number of odd numbers. So I came up with an idea to use an extra parameter(cnt) every recursive step.

The bottom pseudo code is not working, it it just my basic idea. Can someone please give me some hints or ideas?

```
    def count_even(L):
      def helper(L, cnt):
        if L is empty return 0
        elif cnt == 3 return 1 # when odd numbers >= 3 then it returns
        elif L[0] is even? return helper(L[0], count+1) # increment cnt
        elif L[0] is list? # if detects inner loop, then another recursion
          inner_list = L[0]
          return helper(inner_list[0], 0) + helper(inner_list[1:], 0)
        else: # L[0] is not even
          return helper(L[1:], count)

     # calling a helper function with cnt=0
     helper(L, 0)
```

Comment: Try using recursive depth first search approach here. Whenever you encounter a `list`, call the recursive function and then call your `helper` function to count consecutive odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using a wrapper, we could examine a recursion that counts both the odd elements for the current list as well as the count for list elements. We can also just use an index to mark where we are and avoid unnecessary copying (this recursion could be used with or without a wrapper, depending on your needs):

```
# Returns a tuple:
# (this_list, total)
def f(L, i):
  if i == len(L):
    return (0,0)

  this_list, total = f(L, i + 1)

  if isinstance(L[i], list):
    return (this_list, total + f(L[i], 0)[1])

  if this_list == "list counted" or not (L[i] & 1):
    return (this_list, total)

  if this_list == 2:
    return ("list counted", total + 1)

  return (this_list + 1, total)

print f ([1, 2, 3, 5, [3, 3, 3, [5,5,5]]], 0) # ('list counted', 3)
print f ([1, 2, 3, 4, [3, 3, 3, [5,5,5]]], 0) # (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. Could be shorter but this is more readable Just count the number of odds you have returning 1 if you have more than 3, if you hit a `list` object, just call your function again. This works for nested lists too.

```
def count_even(L):
    c = 0
    numberOfOddsInList = 0
    for i in L:
        if type(i) is list:
            numberOfOddsInList = count_even(i)
        else:
            if i % 2 == 1:
                c+=1
    return (c >= 3) + numberOfOddsInList


print(count_even([1, 2, 3, 1, [3, 3, 3,[1,1,1]]]))# returns 3
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use any loops :/